# How to print \n in windows?

Tags: c, matlab, mingw

I need to print a newline character to a file with a C program running in windows and compiling with MinGW. However, it has to print `\n` only, instead of `\r\n`.

Take for example the following program:

```
#include <stdio>

void main() {
    FILE * fid = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fid, "\n");
    fclose(fid);
}
```

Reading the created file in Matlab with the command:

`text = int32(fileread('out.txt'))`

Yields:

`1x2 int32 row vector`

`13 10`

Yet, somehow, I need it to print only `10` and not the `13` (=`\r`) character.

Comment: The way that a newline is interpreted varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode so that the NL to CRLF mapping used with text files is not done for you.  So:

```
const char filename[] = "out.txt";
FILE *fid = fopen(filename, "wb");
if (fid == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for binary writing\n", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

(assuming you include `<stdlib.h>` too).  I don't recommend `void main()` — the correct standard definition for no arguments is `int main(void)`, and then you could use `return 1;` instead of `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` to report the error to the environment.  See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for more information.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks for the code quality feedback as well.